# What photo management software to use on local network with NAS and both Mac and Windows clients?

Tags: lightroom, software, storage, photo-management, picasa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggestions for shared cross-platform photo management?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12377/suggestions-for-shared-cross-platform-photo-management)

I am looking for photo management software that will work in the following environment:

- Photos all stored in a central location on the NAS
- Supports both Mac and Windows clients
- Recognizes changes made (i.e. my wife uploads photos and creates an album on her Mac and it will show up next time I open the photo manager on my windows laptop)
- I am okay with it being a single user environment (i.e. we both can't be in the photo manager making changes at the same time)

Picasa doesn't seem to support this setup and I'm having a hard time finding a solution to what I thought would be a common software need.

I have looked at Lightroom, but it costs $299 and I understand I'd have to buy 2 licenses.  Seems expensive when I'm really only doing very basic editing like what picasa supports.

Please help!