# What system should I use for photo management and sharing over the Internet?

Tags: file-management, cropping, photo-management, linux

This question has been [asked before](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19421/what-system-should-i-use-for-photo-management-and-sharing-over-a-lan), but the answers are 3+ years old and nearly all of the projects referenced are gone!

Basically, I want something that does everything Picasa (the Windows client application) does, but on the web.  I would like to do some simple editing of my pictures inside the browser (crop, rotate, some simple changes with lighting and shadows and contrast).  Then I want to pick which of my photos I share with the world, and publish those albums.

This seems to be a very common request, but I can't find any solutions that really work for me!

I've got an Ubuntu server all ready, but no application.  Piwigo doesn't have any editing capabilities, and Coppermine's editing is just plain awful.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried looking at [Linux Equivalents](http://alternativeto.net/software/picasa/?platform=linux)? Depending on your needs, you might find something workable from this constantly updated list.

Also online storage services similar to Dropbox, Box, iCloud, etc., offer simple image manipulation as part of their photo sharing features. They are constantly updating editing features of the sharing apps. Although most improvements are being made either to filters or to integrate with mobile apps that can edit, save, send, share from both the mobile device and the desktop.

Comment: This question is about hosting web apps on a linux server, not running client side apps like in your link. I'm not sure the editing offered by Dropbox or iCloud would fulfil the OP's requirements.

Comment: Some of the apps that show Linux Equivalents use in-browser editing no matter where the files are located, desktop or server.